# CREAR MAS TEXTFIELD OCN BOTON LARAVEL

Tags: laravel-5

no tengo una idea clara de como realizarlo, así que necesito su opinión, les explico:

Necesito que al momento de apretar el botón "+", se agreguen los textfield "Nombre", "Agregar Insumo", "Insumo", "Unidad de Medida" y "cantidad", hacia abajo.
Alguna Solución o ayuda?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]